# Is multicast delegate create new reference for each chaining?

Tags: c#, delegates, multicast

Is multicast delegate create new reference for each chaining? or its a value type (MSDN says otherwise)? I don't understand, please take look at the following code.

```
using System;
class TestClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Action origin = new Action(() => { Console.WriteLine("1st line"); });
        Action copyFromOrigin;

        copyFromOrigin = origin;
        origin += new Action(() => { Console.WriteLine("2nd line"); });

        copyFromOrigin.Invoke();

        //result is "1st line", why the "2nd line" is missing? 
        //shouldn't the copyFromOrigin is referencing the origin?
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegates are immutable....

When you add a new handler a new *delegate* is created.

Under the hood it calls the [Delegate.Combine Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.combine?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Delegate_Combine_System_Delegate_System_Delegate_)

> Concatenates the invocation lists of two delegates.
>
> **Returns**
>
> **A new delegate with an invocation list that concatenates the
> invocation lists of a and b in that order**. Returns a if b is null,
> returns b if a is a null reference, and returns a null reference if
> both a and b are null references.

You can see it in action [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLRWQTwHYGNXIxJQC2yANACYgDUAPgAIAMABAwIwDcAsAFAMBmNgCYWAYRYBvPi1lshDACwsAsgAoAlFJlzdeuR1EB7BAEsA5qewsAvC2wQA7m3bC1m2wD4pLgJxqAInZCFgAbKwgAjU4WAF9onX1DFlwjAAdMADEEIxIAeTNLbB5eRL1UjOzcgosrWxYTWuKy3Uailho7B2dDdy0bb0k/QOFsSjCIqJj4kpa5Cqyc/MKrADoASWwANyMAawhNWd59WQB6U6RkOFCYFlNkFiCQ8IcA8hZHAAtMFhhPiEeo3GL0idweJHuyCs5gA/Cw5mdTshPkZrpRsAByW5/AELKrLJpglhISBIPDQ37/BorbAwhHiIzYZBGUIQVYAJWglAA0hBMIcyrE+LEgA===)

```
Action action = <>c.<>9__0_0 ?? (<>c.<>9__0_0 = new Action(<>c.<>9.<M>b__0_0));
Action action2 = action;
action = (Action)Delegate.Combine(action, <>c.<>9__0_1 ?? (<>c.<>9__0_1 = new Action(<>c.<>9.<M>b__0_1)));
action2();
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it's immutable type and each assignment creates new instance  copied from original one. Note it's still reference type but just of special kind.